# SQL: Variable string input in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, kaggle

I'm trying to generalize a SQL command by putting it into a function and having the WHERE clause be a string variable that can be inputted by a user.

This is from a Kaggle SQL tutorial, based on the stackoverflow bigquery public dataset.

```
topic = "bigquery"

bigquery_experts_query = """
                         SELECT a.owner_user_id AS user_id, COUNT(1) AS number_of_answers
                         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                         INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                             ON q.id = a.parent_id
                         WHERE q.tags LIKE '%{topic}%'
                         GROUP BY user_id 
                         ORDER BY number_of_answers DESC
                         """
```

They have `'%{topic}%'` as supposedly allowing for "topic" to be any string, in this case "bigquery" as declared above.
However this returns an empty pandas dataframe when doing `.to_dataframe()` on the results of the query, whereas

```
bigquery_experts_query = """
                         SELECT a.owner_user_id AS user_id, COUNT(1) AS number_of_answers
                         FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                         INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                             ON q.id = a.parent_id
                         WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                         GROUP BY user_id 
                         ORDER BY number_of_answers DESC
                         """
```

works the way it's supposed to.

I think Kaggle uses MySQL but I'm not sure. How do I get a variable string to work in this context so that I can generalize this SQL command into a function?

Answer (score 1):

Use a Stored Procedure to construct (via `CONCAT`) and then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` it.